# Replace characters from string Ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line, sed

I have the following string which has an array element in it and I will like to remove the quotes in the array element to the outside of the array:

```
"date":"2014-05-04","name":"John","products":["12","14","45"],"status":"completed"
```

Is there a way to remove the double quotes in [] and add double quotes to the start and end of []?  Results:

```
"date":"2014-05-04","name":"John","products":"[12,14,45]","status":"completed"
```

Can that be done in ruby or is there a command line that I can use?

Comment: Your lines that begin `String "date"` and `Rusults "date"` are not strings.  Do you mean the first to be `'"2014-05-04","name":"John","products":["12","14","45"],"status":"completed"'`?  (Note the single quotes I've added.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string looks like a json hash to me:

```
json = '{"date":"2014-05-04","name":"John","products":["12","14","45"],"status":"completed"}'

require 'json'

hash = JSON.load(json)
hash.update('products' => hash['products'].map(&:to_i))

puts hash.to_json
# => {"date":"2014-05-04","name":"John","products":[12,14,45],"status":"completed"}
```

Or if you really want to have the array represented as a string (what is not json anymore):

```
hash.update('products' => hash['products'].map(&:to_i).to_s) # note .to_s here

puts hash.to_json
# => {"date":"2014-05-04","name":"John","products":"[12,14,45]","status":"completed"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @spickermann is pretty good, and the best way I can think of, but since I had fun trying to find an alternative without using json, here it goes:

```
def string_to_result(str)
  str.match(/(?:\[)((?:")+(.)+(?:")+)+(?:\])/)
  str.gsub($1, "#{$1.split(',').map{ |num| num.gsub('"', '') }.join(',')}").gsub(/\[/, '"[').gsub(/\]/, ']"').gsub(/String/, 'Results')
end
```

Is ugly as hell, but it works :P
I tried to do it on a single step, but that was way harder for my regexp skills.

Anyway, you should never parse something structured such as json or xml using only regexps, and this is merely for fun.

[EDIT] Had the bracket adjacent quotes wrong,sorry. Fixed.
Also, one more thing, this fails A LOT! An empty array or an array in other place in the string are just a few cases where it would fail.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the form of [String#gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes a block:

```
str = '"2014-05-04","name":"John","products":["12","14","45"],"status":"completed"'

puts str.gsub(/\["(\d+)","(\d+)","(\d+)"\]/) { "\"[#{$1},#{$2},#{$3}]\"" }
  #"2014-05-04","name":"John","products":"[12,14,45]","status":"completed"
```